# Apostol's proof on uniform convergence and continuity

Tags: continuity, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

> Assume that $f_n\to f$ on $S$ uniformly. If each $f_n$ is continuous at $c\in S$. Then the limit function $f$ is also continuous at $c$.

In the proof it has been stated that the theorem is obvious for an isolated point. That is, if $c$ is an isolated point then $f$ is automatically continuous at $c$. So we only consider accumulation points in the proof. Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beacause *every* function is continuous at an isolated point. If $c$ is such a point and $f$ is your function, saying that $f$ is continuous at $c$ means that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in D_f):d(x,c)<\delta\implies d\bigl(f(x),f(c)\bigr)<\varepsilon.$$Let $\varepsilon>0$ and take $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,c)<\delta\implies x=c$; such a $\delta$ must exist, since $c$ is an isolated point. But then$$d(x,c)<\delta\implies x=c\implies d\bigl(f(x),f(c)\bigr)=0<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Also sir is it correct to say that the points inside $S$ are either limit points or isolated (i.e, these 2 concepts are mutually exclusive for the points inside $S$)? And that is why Apostol moved over to limit points after stating the theorem to be obvious for isolated points?

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha I don't have access to Apostol's book now, but if his definition of *limit point* is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition), then you are right.

Answer (score 4):

Because $c$ is an isolated point, there exist $\delta>0$ such that $B(c,\delta)=\{c\}$. Therefore;
\begin{equation}
|f(x)-f(c)| = 0 < \epsilon \quad if \quad x\in B(c,\delta)
\end{equation}
where $B(c,\delta)$ is the ball  centered at $c$.